# Merging the two concepts of conditional probability/expectation

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

One can condition the probability of an event or the expectation of a random variable on an event that has positive probability or on a $\sigma$-Algebra. While I think that I understand both concepts on their own I have trouble making sense of a combined version. So let $X,Y$ be random variables and f be a measurable function. If A is an event with $\mathbb{P}(A)>0$, how can I interpret
$$\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y) \mid\, A \mid\, Y]$$
or maybe it would be written as
$$\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y) \mid\, A, Y]?$$
I am having trouble translating even the simple rules of conditional expectation on a sigma Algebra to this. For example if $X$ is $\sigma(Y)$ measurable how would I pull $f(X,Y)$ out of the expectation?

Comment: We know that w.r.t. an event $A$ the conditional probability $\mathbb P(B|A)$ is $\mathbb P(B\cap A)/\mathbb P(A)$ and this produces a probability measure $\mu(B)$ w.r.t. which we can take a conditional expectation $\mathbb E_\mu[f(X,Y)]$ which is a number which we may write as $\mathbb E[f(X,Y)|A]\,.$ The other concept of conditional expectation is the one w.r.t. a random variable $\mathbb E[f(X,Y)|Y]\,.$
When $f$ is constant this is a number. Likewise we know that $\mathbb E[\mathbb E[f(X,Y)|A]|Y]$ is a number.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but then, other questions arise for me. If for example $A=\{f(X,Y)=0\}$, then, assuming $\mathbb{P}(A)>0$ we get $\mathbb{E}_\mu[f(X,Y) | X,Y] = f(X,Y)$ and not $0$ which seems very strange to me.

Comment: Arguably the notation used for conditional expectations can be confusing sometimes. It is therefore even more important that you don't trust it blindly. It is true that $\mathbb{E}[f(X,Y) | X,Y] = f(X,Y)$ but in your case $f(X,Y)=0$ $\mathbb P_{\color{red}{\mu}}$-almost surely. Therefore, $\mathbb{E}_{\color{red}{\mu}}[f(X,Y) | X,Y]$ is zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is an event or a random variable then the notation $\operatorname{E}[X|A]$ have different meanings. Suppose that $X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ where $(\Omega ,\mathcal{F},P)$ is a probability space, then when $A$ is an event with positive probability then $\operatorname{E}[X|A]$ represents the mean value of $X|_A$ in the probability space $(A,\mathcal{F}|_A,P[\,\cdot\, |A])$, where $\mathcal{F}|_A:=\{B\cap A:B\in \mathcal{F}\}$ is a trace $\sigma $-algebra (the trace generated by $A$).

When $A$ is a random variable then $\operatorname{E}[X|A]:=\operatorname{E}[X|\sigma (A)]$ where $\sigma (A):=\{A^{-1}(D):D\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$ is the $\sigma $-algebra generated by $A$, and where (as you surely knows) $\operatorname{E}[X|A]$ is a random variable defined by the relation
$$
\int_{F}\operatorname{E}[X|A]dP=\int_{F}X dP,\text{ for every }F\in \sigma (A)
$$

Notice that, with the definitions given above, there is a slight difference between $\operatorname{E}[X|A]$ and $\operatorname{E}[X|\mathbf{1}_{A}]$ when $A$ is an event of positive probability, as the first is just a number and the second is a random variable that is $\sigma (\mathbf{1}_{A})$-measurable.

By the other hand something like $\operatorname{E}[X|A|B]$ is undefined as far as someone defines explicitly what this notation means. By the other I never had seen something like $\operatorname{E}[X|A,Y]$ where $A$ is an event and $Y$ a random variable, so it meaning must be defined previously to make sense.